# Performance of Phenom II X6 processor in Ubuntu

Tags: amd-processor

I've never used Ubuntu before, and I will be using it for the first time. My question is whether the functions relative to the cores of the Phenom II X6 1090T Black Edition processor have been perfected. I have an incompatibility with HoN and the hard disk usage is up to 100%, so I'm going to Ubuntu to find out which operating system is more stable. Have they perfected the technology for this processor?

Comment: la traduccion no es buena, la verdad no se porque, soy nuevo en esto

Comment: English please. I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: Download ubuntu, then download yumi and create a multiboot USB, set the priority of the bios, but every time I reboot does not start installing Linux, I do not know what could be wrong? or am I doing wrong? but I can not install the operating system with Windows 8.1

features

ASUS PC motherboard Hibrit CFX CPU phenon IIX6 1090T, video Gigabyte GT 240 1Gb, 4 GB of RAM

Comment: I have not installed ubuntu, this is the first time I install it as going to be a duplicate, plus the installation does not start preceso

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu will be fine on this processor. Make sure you do a backup.